# Can computer software that doesn't use databases still beat best in world?

Tags: engines

Are there strong chess engines that can beat most of the good chess engines without using databases (like opening databases), solely using brute force?

Comment: Well.... The question is a very simple YES.

Answer (score 4):

In the recent [Nakamura - Stockfish match](http://schach.chess.com/news/stockfish-outlasts-nakamura-3634), Stockfish played with a one pawn handicap.

Additionally "**According to match conditions, Stockfish was not allowed to access either an opening book or an endgame tablebase.**".

Without opening database and with a one pawn handicap, Stockfish still beat Nakamura quite handily 3-1.

Comment: I did not realize computer software/hardware have come this far.   Has the software come up with new openings that humans have never thought of before.

Comment: @stevek I think you underestimated computer chess. Lots of chess openings played by the top players are analyzed by computers.